# How to insert JtextField value to a Jtable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield

```
 public LayoutWindow() {
    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Receipt No:");

    txtReceiptNo = new JTextField();
    txtReceiptNo.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblDate = new JLabel("Date:");

    txtDate = new JTextField();
    txtDate.setColumns(10);
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String newDate = dateFormate.format(date);
    txtDate.setText(newDate);


    JLabel lblProductCode = new JLabel("Product Code");

    txtProductCode = new JTextField();
    txtProductCode.setColumns(10);
    String a = txtProductCode.getText();
    txtProductCode.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
      public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        warn();
      }
      public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        warn();
      }
      public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        warn();
      }

      public void warn() {
         System.out.println("changed....");
         txtQuantity.setText("1");


      }
    });

    JLabel lblQuantity = new JLabel("Quantity");

    txtQuantity = new JTextField();
    txtQuantity.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblPrice = new JLabel("Price");

    txtPrice = new JTextField();
    txtPrice.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblNetAmount = new JLabel("Net Amount");

    txtNetAmount = new JTextField();
    txtNetAmount.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblDiscount = new JLabel("Discount");

    txtDiscount = new JTextField();
    txtDiscount.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblTotal = new JLabel("Total");

    txtTotal = new JTextField();
    txtTotal.setColumns(10);



    System.out.println(a);
    String[] columnNames = {"Product Code","Description","Price","Quantity","Total"};
    Object[][] data = {{a, "bb","cc", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},};

    final JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);

    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

    if (DEBUG) {
        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                printDebugData(table);
            }
        });
    }

    //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
```

I have a code like above. I want to insert data into Jtable which is comes from Jtextfield.
And I also want to clear JtextField data `onFocus`. How can I do that?
Plz help me soon... thanx...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames)` constructs a `DefaultTableModel`

You can add a new row into a `DefaultTableModel` using [`DefaultTableModel#addRow(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) or [`DefaultTableModel#addRow(Vector)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.util.Vector%29).

Under your example that would require something like `((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel).addRow(...)`

To set the value of an already existing row, you can use the `TableModel#setValueAt(row, col)` method.

This would be a simple as `table.getModel().setValueAt(row, col)`, where row and col are `int` values.

You may need to convert the row index from the view to the model via [`JTable#convertRowIndexToModel(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel%28int%29) and the column index to the model as well using [`Table#convertColumnIndexToModel(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertColumnIndexToModel%28int%29) in case the rows have being sorted or the columns moved by the user

At lot of this is covered in [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), well worth your time

To clear a text field on focus gained, you will need a [`FocusListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusListener.html) and attach it to each field you want to enable.

Something like...

```
public class ClearOnFocusGained implements FocusListener {
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        // This is an assumption...
        ((JTextComponent)e.getComponent()).setText(null);
    }
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {}
}
```

Then you would simply create an instance of the listener and apply to each of your fields

```
ClearOnFocusGained clearListener = new ClearOnFocusGained();
txtTotal.addFocusListener(clearListener);
```

Comment: disagree with FocusListener, lets for JButtons whatever,

Comment: @mKorbel How would you suggest the OP achieve the ability to clear the text field on focus gained??

Comment: I woudn't be to sue `FocusListener`, to create `JButton "Clear me"`, I haven't any issue with code from your answer, just with OPs logics to clear whatever on `focusGained()`

Comment: @mKorbel I'm always interested in alternative approaches, that's why asked. Good point though